# Can perform partial searches without fieldname in solr

Tags: java, solr

I am trying to perform a partial search on a field in solr.
`my_id: ABC_00123`

I would like to search for 123 and see this item. I cannot get it to work without using the my_id field in the query.

In my schema.xml I have put:

```
  <fieldType name="text_ngrm" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">

      <analyzer type="index">
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
          <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="50" />

          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Then (I'm not sure this is necessary):

```
<field name="_text_ngrm_" type="text_ngrm" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

I also have:

```
<field name="my_id" type="text_ngrm" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Finally:

```
<copyField source="my_id" dest="_text_ngrm_"/>
```

For the query this works:
`my_id: 223`

But 223 on it's own does not. I have the feeling it has to do with this copyField definition.

The only way, I could get it to work was to change:

```
<initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/tvrh,/elevate,/spell,/browse">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">_text_ngrm_</str>   
    </lst>
</initParams>
```

But this breaks all my other default searches. Is there not some way to add like:

```
<initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/tvrh,/elevate,/spell,/browse">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">_text_</str>   
      <str name="df">_text_ngrm_</str>   
    </lst>
</initParams>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You can supply the default search field in the URL when querying by providing the `df` yourself - so that for your single query, you can supply `&df=_text_ngrm_` - since that's the field you want to search.

You can also use the edismax handler to search both - use `qf=_text_ _text_ngrm_` - you can also apply different weights to the fields in that case, for example to give more exact hits a higher boost - `qf=_text_^5 _text_ngrm_` will give five time higher weight to hits in the `_text_` field compared to the `_text_ngrm_` field.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for your help. ;-)